# Elasticsearch - How to remove stuck persistent setting after upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch

I have just upgraded my cluster from `5.6` to `6.1`. I did a rolling upgrade as the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html) specified. It looks like a setting that I was using isn't available anymore in 6.1. That would've been fine, but now I can't even enable my shard allocation, so now my last node won't allocate its shards. Doing something as simple as this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "persistent" : {
        "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "all"
    }
}
```

results in this:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason" : "[inoreader-es4][92.247.179.253:9300][cluster:admin/settings/update]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "unknown setting [indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec] did you mean [indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec]?"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

No matter what setting I try to change I always get this error.
Yes, I did set `indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec` as persistent setting once in 5.x, and I'm OK with having to set it to a new name now, but how can I even remove it? It's not in `elasticsearch.yml`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to unset that value. If you are still on the old version, you can use the following command (in 5.0 unsetting with `null` was added):

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec": null
  }
}
```

This will however fail with a "persistent setting [indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec], not recognized" in your cluster if you have already upgraded.

At the moment (Elasticsearch version 6.1.1) the removed setting will be archived under `archived.indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec`. You can remove this and any other archived setting with:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "archived.*": null
  }
}
```

However, there is [a bug that only lets you unset archived settings before you change any other settings](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28026).

If you have already made other settings and are affected by this bug, the only solution is to downgrade to 5.6 again, unset the configuration (command at the top of this answer), and then do the upgrade again. It's probably enough to do this on one node (stop all others) as long as it's the master and all other nodes join that master and accept its corrected cluster state. Be sure to take a snapshot before in any case.

For future versions the `archived.*` behavior will probably change as stated [in the ticket](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28026#issuecomment-355569742) (though it's just in the planning phase right now):

> [...] we should not archive unknown and broken cluster settings.
>   Instead, we should fail to recover the cluster state. The solution for
>   users in an upgrade case would be to rollback to the previous version,
>   address the settings that would be unknown or broken in the next major
>   version, and then proceed with the upgrade.

Manually editing or even deleting the cluster state on disk sounds very risky: The cluster state includes a lot of information (check for yourself with `GET /_cluster/state`) like templates, indices, routing table,... Even if you have the data of the data nodes, but you lost the cluster state, you wouldn't be able to access your data (the "map" how to form indices out of the shards is missing). If I remember correctly, in more recent ES versions the data nodes cache the cluster state and will try to restore from that, but that's a last resort and I wouldn't want to rely on it. Also I'm not sure if that might not also bring back your bad setting.

PS: I can highly recommend the free [upgrade assistant](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-upgrade-assistant.html) going from 5.6 to 6.x.

Comment: Yes, setting this (and any other transient or persistent setting) to the cluster fails with the same message. That’s very bad news... my cluster is 8TB and I really don’t like the idea of downgrading it... I am thinking of shutting down all nodes as deleting the cluster state file in each one. Of course I will back it up first. I know the setting is stored there, but it’s a binary file and I don’t feel comfortable editing it. Do you think it’s safe to delete the cluster state file? Will the master nodes recreate it without this pesky persistent setting? Thanks!

Comment: I've expanded my answer: Maybe you can just downgrade a single node and work your magic from that. And be careful with the cluster state — that's actually vital information for any cluster and needs to be kept around and backed up as well.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far! I just tried that solution - stopped all nodes, downgraded one master eligible node, nulled the setting and upgraded it again. However it refused to start - `failed to read [id:84, legacy:false, file:/home/elasticsearch/nodes/0/_state/global-84.st]
` "Index patterns must not be null or empty; got null". I had to manually copy a state file from another node so I can bring back my cluster to life... Of course the setting is there again but renamed... unknown setting [archived.indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec]. I will try again on another node later.

Comment: So in a brief moment of insanity I decided to try and set that "new" setting `archived.indices.store.throttle.max_bytes_per_sec` to `null`. It actually aknowledged and now the problem is gone! Go figure....

Comment: Interesting. Let me know if that fixed your cluster and you could make it to 6.x

Comment: Yes, this actually happened after I upgraded the node back to 6.1 and started the whole cluster. So the problem is now solved, but I'm not exactly sure how.

Comment: Ah, so `archived.*` should always be available after the upgrade, but you can only unset it as the very first command right now. A colleague just opened an issue and I hope this will be fixed in the future: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28026

Comment: Very interesting! OK So maybe you can add a separate answer with the "archived" solution and I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've rewritten my initial answer to avoid any confusion for future readers.